# How to set timezone aws buildspec

Tags: amazon-web-services, timezone, aws-codecommit

I need to append the current local timestamp to the name of a file created using buildspec.yml 
Using the following, I can append the timestamp. But it's in UTC. How can I set the timezone so that the name will have local time?

```
zip -r xxx-$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%m%S).zip .
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48101/how-can-i-have-date-output-the-time-from-a-different-timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, Asdfg.

```
zip -r xxx-$(env TZ=Australia/Melbourne date +%Y%m%d_%H%m%S).zip
```